# Sort files based upon variable length of numeric digits in their name C#

Tags: linq, sorting, blender

I'm writing a program to Monitor Blender rendering projects.
But I have a problem of sorting the output of blender (a 3d program).
it generates files in numeric format. Or in some text then ending in a numeric format.

The problem here is that it numbers like:
someprojectname-0001.png
someprojectname-0010.png
someprojectname-10104.png
**someprojectname-10105.png**
**someprojectname-9999.png**

There could be some text before the numbers but the problem seams that so far any sorting I tried, sees 9999 higher than 10104 (some how the problem is extra digits, and the number of digits isn't fixed either.

it should output
someprojectname-0001.png
someprojectname-0010.png
**someprojectname-9999.png

someprojectname-10104.png**

essentially concat all numbers (ignore any text), then order by number, so i tried:

```
d = new DirectoryInfo(renderpath);

//  FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles( rendertpye).OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToArray();

FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles(rendertpye).OrderByDescending(o => string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Name)).ThenBy(o =>
            {
                int result;
                if (Int32.TryParse(o.Name, out result))
                { return result; }
                else
                { return Int32.MaxValue; }
            }).ToArray();
```

I also tried Numeric beforeAlpha sort ( https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/543502/Numeric-before-alpha-sort-in-LINQ )
And I tried ( https://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting).

The problem though neither they can handle the non fixed numeric length of blenders file numbering.

**update**
My goal here is not to put rules on how people save their BlendFiles, the program requires an array that retrieves all saved files, and sorts based upon the number in the filename, which can be of variable digit size.

I tried it with linq, but I begin to doubt it can be done directly with Linq.
Maybe though it can if we create a int list based upon filename, then order that list and use that one to order the original text named list.

Comment: your file name is going to be like name-number.png right ?

Comment: You need to extract the number from the filename, possibly that means getting the text between the `-` and the `.`, but without knowing the format of the `someprojectname` prefix, it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: The project name in blender can be anything soeven the - is not always there. I dont want to alter Blender setttings, as so far the could would work on a allready running blender project, as i want to give it away for free, it should not add naming complexity to end users, its something to be solved by coding.

Comment: you need to fix your input string , check my answer i provided threee way based on your input, and if you just want to extract number from string then you just use regex way ...

Comment: myBlend123, myBlend1230001, MyBlend12310001   
(largest numeric last)

Comment: @user3800527 -for this kind of input you can try out `GetFilNumberRegxWay` added in my answer just and also replied in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, created a struct (which is not ideal for this), on which i added a int counter for each fileinfo entry. And some regex to scrub text from filenames, the function keeps original names, and fileInfo but returns them sorted by the numbers they contain.

A future extension might be to also sort on last modified property
that might be easier. and a slight improvement might be to only find numbers in the end of the name as project2-frame33.blend would become problematic.
probably some clever regex could do that.

```
struct numericfile
    {
        public int filenr; public FileInfo file;
    }
public List<FileInfo> SortedbyNumber(List<FileInfo> files)
    {
        List<numericfile> filesnrs = new List<numericfile>();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            numericfile nf = new numericfile();
            nf.filenr = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(file.Name, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty));
            nf.file = file;
            filesnrs.Add(nf);
        }
        filesnrs.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.filenr.CompareTo(s2.filenr));
        files.Clear();
        foreach (numericfile fnr in filesnrs)
        {
            files.Add(fnr.file);
        }
        return files;
    }
```

Comment: nf.filenr= Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(file.Name, @"/\d+$/"));

Comment: This won't work for Project123 as base name. A better solution would have to find the common part of all filenames first. Only then can you know the sequence number.

Comment: it does work for project123 and even for project2frame-2004.blend
if you use my own last  comment (which takes any number from then end of the name of any digit length- correction it starts working if project123 then + one or more text characters (or - ) and then numbers.